# Prevent pre-populate of React Hook Forms

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache, react-hook-form, clear-cache

I have a [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for registration, and every time I visit, the form gets pre-filled with data from the cache. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Did you try this: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-autocomplete-off ?